# achartengine - adding External ImageButtons for zoom on view next to chart causes strange UI behavior

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I wanted to have Button on the view on the top of my chart view.

PROBLEM:

When I press the Button the clone of chart view appears squeezed at the back of pressed button.It is there for only one second and then disappears. Look at the print screen...

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8MKY.jpg)

Does anybody have a clue why this happens?

I'm attaching dummy source code:

layout (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layXzoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnXzoomOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

    import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
    import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
    import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
    import org.achartengine.chart.TimeChart;
    import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
    import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class TestgraphActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    private GraphicalView mChartView;
    private TimeSeries time_series;

    // chart container
    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        // create dataset and renderer
        mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(3f);

        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);

        time_series = new TimeSeries("test");

        mDataset.addSeries(time_series);

        fillData();

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
                "H:mm:ss");

        layout.addView(mChartView);
    }

    private void fillData() {
        long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            time_series.add(new Date(value + i * TimeChart.DAY / 4), i);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Toni

Answer (score 1):

toni has also posted this question on the aChartEngine issues tracker where it has been answered (to a degree).

Link to the issue: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=171

Solution summary:

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```

which seems to take care of the artifacting.