# achartengine custom zoom buttons

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Is there an easy way to use custom images for Zoom Buttons?
I'd like to use default setZoomButtonsVisible functions to manage
show/hide buttons.

How can I override those buttons?

I'd like to use icons from my res/drawable (drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi ..)
to make sure images will be good looking on all screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using almost the same way I think. I've got:

```
renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
```

And I'm using .xml file for my buttons layout. I'm not using `<ImageButton>` in my code. I'm using `<Button>` with background. And in this way these buttons are images. My code for button:

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/zoomin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/action_zoomin"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide original zoom buttons and enable external zoom:

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer; //or any of other renderer
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
mRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);

//then add click events tot he imagebuttons on the view
//mChartView --> private GraphicalView mChartView;

    ImageButton btnZoomIn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomIn);

    btnZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChartView.zoomIn();

            }
    });

    ImageButton  btnZoomOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomOut );

    btnZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChartView.zoomOut();
            }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

The only problem is that some strange think is happening on the click. I posted problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021959/achartengine-adding-external-imagebuttons-for-zoom-on-view-next-to-chart-cause) and also as an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=171).

Hope somebody will find an answer.

Toni

Comment: Thanks. I've just did it today. In the same way :)
I don't have this issue. Or I'm testing it wrong.

Comment: @adek do you use relative layout or linear layout for holder of the graph. Can you paste the whole xml? Thanks, Toni

Comment: This is my XML:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="false">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:background="#FFFFFF" 
android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

#my buttons
 <LinearLayout><Buttons/></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Hi. I tryed Button with background and it is working. When button is passsive - doesn't have the onRollOver graphics all is OK. But if button is changing view on rollover it is acting the same way... Strange... Thank you @adek.