# achartengine zoom button size

Tags: android, achartengine

Can I change the size of the zoom button on achartengine? I know I can use my own custom implementation of the buttons, but I would like to use the achartengine zoom buttons.

If changing the size of the zoom button is not an option, does anybody know of holo theme zoom buttons? I noticed btn_zoom is no longer on android drawables after 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the size of the zoom buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I did this by designing the custom buttons and hiding the default buttons. Check this discussion
  [achartengine custom zoom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142212/achartengine-custom-zoom-buttons)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please don't post comments or questions as answers. If the provided answers to this question do not help you, you may ask a seperate question explaining why the answers here do not address your problem.